# insert copied cell values [vba]

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code it copies a certain range and paste inserts it in the next worksheet, but it copies formulas, I want it to insert the amount of rows copied and paste values only.

```
Sub create_payroll()
'copies values from 'Driver' Worksheet (till last row) and pastes values into Invoice Data A14
Dim LastRow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
LastRow = Worksheets("Driver").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Driver").Range("A3:H" & LastRow).Copy
Sheets("Invoice Data").Range("A14").Insert xlShiftDown
```

Comment: This may help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020670/excel-vba-how-to-insert-values-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020670/excel-vba-how-to-insert-values-only)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA - How to insert values only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020670/excel-vba-how-to-insert-values-only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like the following:

```
Sub create_payroll()
    'copies values from 'Driver' Worksheet (till last row) and pastes values into Invoice Data A14
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim srcRng As Range
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Sheets("Driver")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set srcRng = .Range("A3:H" & LastRow)
    End With


    With Sheets("Invoice Data")
        .Range("A14").Resize(srcRng.Rows.Count - 1, srcRng.Columns.Count).Insert shift:=xlDown
        .Range("A14").Resize(srcRng.Rows.Count, srcRng.Columns.Count).Value = srcRng.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you works great. Except if I have 4 rows of data, it pastes only 3

Comment: Like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Or bypass the clipboard entirely:

```
Sheets("Invoice Data").Range("A14:H" & LastRow + 11).Value = Sheets("Driver").Range("A3:H" & LastRow).Value
```

To bypass the clipboard and insert rows use:

```
Sheets("Invoice Data").Rows("14:").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Sheets("Invoice Data").Range("A14:H" & LastRow + 11).Value = Sheets("Driver").Range("A3:H" & LastRow).Value
```

Comment: I need it to insert rows and paste values.